# How to determine an adjoint map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $V = \text{span}( \{\sin x, \cos x \})$ over $\mathbb R$ with inner product
$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^\pi f(x) g(x)\ dx$.

Consider the derivative map $D : V \to V$. Determine the adjoint map $D^*$ by first determining the matrix $[D^*]$ in respect to an orthonormal basis and then calculating $D^*(a \sin(x) + b \cos(x))$ where
$a, b \in \mathbb R$.

I found an orthonormal basis to be: $B = \left \{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sin(x), \ - \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cos(x) \right \}$

I believe my adjoint map is the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

How do I calculate $D^* (a \sin(x) + b \cos(x))$ where $a, b \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, which is much more readable than trying to use ascii art. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: $\sin x=\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\, \sqrt{2\over \pi}\, \sin x.$ Similarly  $\cos x=-\sqrt{\pi\over 2}\, (-1)\sqrt{2\over \pi}\, \cos x$